# Cannot call method to completion from under task.IsFaulted condition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, exception, firebase-authentication, task

I'm implementing Firebase authentication for my Unity game. I am trying to call a method to display the error after the `SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync` task is done (I enter faulty email) and `IsFaulted` is *true*.

This method I am calling is `ErrorTest` and it creates a string list and calls `DisplayError`. However the `DisplayError` method does not run to completion.

`Debug.Log ("Activating ErrorBox")` line will run (so `DisplayError` starts being executed) but none of the rest gets executed, meaning no game object activation or second `debug.log` call.

There is no error in the editor regarding this. I have tried different things here, changing text property of some components, etc. Only debug calls run until first line of code where something in the game needs to change, and the method stops executing there. Stuck on this big time appreciate any help.

When `Errortest()` is called from a UI Button, `DisplayError()` functions correctly, it does what it's supposed to do, so the fault must lie somewhere within the asynchronous task bit I think.

```
public void ErrorTest () {    
    List<string> testList = new List<string> () {"doodle", "froodle"};
    DisplayError (testList);
}

public void DisplayError (List<string> displayErrorList) {    
     if (displayErrorList != null) {         
         Debug.Log ("Activating ErrorBox");
         errorBox.SetActive (true);
         Debug.Log ("Activated ErrorBox");
         foreach (string error in displayErrorList)
             errorText.text += error + "\n";

     } else {
         Debug.LogError ("Error list doesn't exist");
     }
}

public void SignInWithPassword () {

    string email = emailInput.text.Trim();
    string password = passwordInput.text.Trim();
    auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsCanceled) {
            Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
            return;
        }        
        if (task.IsFaulted) {
            Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
            ErrorTest ();             
            return;
        }
        FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
        Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
           newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);

     });
 }
```

When faulty email is entered the debug log will display the call from inside the lambda expression (the task exception), and the first line of `DisplayError` method. It stops there.

> "SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Firebase.FirebaseException: The email address is badly formatted."
>
> "Activating ErrorBox"

Comment: Most likely experiencing a deadlock. Consider using async event handler.

Comment: The error message says "The email address is badly formatted", so it seems you're passing in an incorrect value there. In a case like that, I usually try to reproduce the problem with hardcoded values, like `auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync("me@my.com", "correcthorsebatterystaple")`. If that works, you know that the problem is in how you get the value from the input. If you have the same problem with the hardcoded values, update your question to show those, as it makes it easier for us to reproduce the problem you're having.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  I might not have clarified well perphaps, I am knowingly entering faulty email to test displaying an error message to the user. I have a separate method which takes the AggregateException and produces a List<string> which it feeds into DisplayError, I did not include it because the problem is reproduceable with the ErrorTest () method which is simpler.

I cannot get the errorbox to display, because displayerror does not run properly.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Unity API can apparently only be executed on the main thread, so after the task is finished you have to dispatch an event to the main thread and queue it there.

This gentleman made a main-thread dispatcher so used that one and it works:

https://github.com/PimDeWitte/UnityMainThreadDispatcher